# Laravel: cannot create correct DELETE action request

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

Unable to create Delete action in Laravel.

I am getting `Not Found` or `Token mismatch` errors all the time.

**My controller:**

```
class TranslationController extends Controller
{
    public function destroy($id)
    {       
        //$id = 1;
        /*$translation = Translation::find($id);
        $translation->delete();*/
    }
    ....
}
```

**Ajax call:**

```
/* Delete given translation */
    var url = "translation";
    var id = 1; 

    $.ajax({
        method: 'DELETE',
        url: url + '/' + id,
        // data: {'id': id, '_token': token},
        success: function() {

        }
    });
```

This would give: `TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:`

If I try:

```
url: url + '/' + id,            
data: {'_token': token},  // token is equal to csrf_token
```

I have: `NotFoundHttpException in Controller.php line 269:`

**Routes:**

```
Route::controller('translation', 'TranslationController');
```

Otherwise I am using Laravel 5 default Middleware, I have not changed anything related to csrf.

Comment: Is that delete route defined inside web middleware? Are you using csrf in the delete form?

Comment: As you see there is no Delete form, I am doing ajax request. I have csrf in middleqare. I do not understand question about "delete route defined inside middleware"? I am suing default Laravel 5 middleware, I have not defined  and changed anything there.I have tried to send token (_token: token), token is defined, but it also fails.

Comment: Oh didn't realise it was ajax, sorry. Anyway, that `url` parameter must be a route defined in `app/Http/routes.php` right? Check Laravel [DOCs about routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#basic-routing): "By default, the routes.php file contains a single route as well as a route group that applies the web middleware group to all routes it contains. This middleware group provides session state and CSRF protection to routes.
Any routes not placed within the web middleware group will not have access to sessions and CSRF protection"

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. I am very new to Laravel. I am using 'token' for csrf updates and I never put them into "somewhere".

Comment: I'm new to Laravel too, studied it a bit this weekend. Maybe you defined the delete route outside the web middleware, this way you won't have access to CSRF protection, but i'm not sure, because I'm new too, but.... I'd check it just in case.

Comment: first of all, you should actually pass `token` that generated from `csrf_token()` function that accessible within the view. so, sometimes, people put this somewhere in the rendered html as hidden field, read that with ajax and pass it along with the request (as a multipart request afaik). however, if you wish to disable this csrf verification, you could refer to this [discussion on selective csrf](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-disable-csrf-middleware-on-certain-routes).

Comment: I already pass have this token generated by csrf_token(), this token is in variable "token" - '_token': token, however, when I pass it I have Not Found exception as I already described above.

Comment: @renathy, check if my answer can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NotFoundHttpException` means that either the route for the particular request *with* the particular **HTTP verb** has not been specified, or the action (*i.e. the controller method*) that is mapped to the verb for the route is wrongly implemented.

Since you've mentioned in the post that the `TranslationController` is defined as an [*implicit* controller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#implicit-controllers),

```
Route::controller('translation', 'TranslationController');
```

and from the controller code you've posted, it's quite obvious that you have not defined the *verb* for the `destroy` method in your controller `TranslationController`.

If you do a `php artisan route:list` in your projects root directory with a terminal/command line interface, you'll see the listing of the registered HTTP verbs, mapping to the corresponding URIs, and the actions.

To define a particular method in an implicit controller, the *verb* (`GET`, `PUT`, `POST`, `DELETE`) should precede the actual function name.
Make sure that the `destroy` method looks like the following in your controller:

```
public function deleteDestroy($id){  
   //delete logic for the resource
}
```

**Note:** 
Laravel by default requires that the `csrf` token is passed along with a particular RESTful request, so do not remove `data: {'_token': token}` from your `AJAX` call.

### Update

Forgot to mention that the `url` in your AJAX call should also be changed to the following in order to work, because this is how Laravel's implicit controllers define the route for a `DELETE` request:

```
var url = "translation/destroy";
```

Comment: Now I have  public function deleteDestroy($id) and ajax call is translation/1 and token is sent in the body. (data: {'_token': token},), still I have NotFound exception.

Comment: I rewrite ajax call: translation/destroy and controller method as you have mentioned, now it works, why?

Comment: Yes of course it should work that way. 
Did you do `php artisan route:list`? If so, you can see that the `DELETE` verb should be mapped to the URI `translation/destroy` (along with the `id` parameter), and NOT `translation`. I'll add it to the answer if you want.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#form-method-spoofing) is documentation about method spoofing. You need to send a POST ajax request with `_method` field set to `DELETE`

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url + '/' + id,
    data: {
        'id': id,
        '_token': token,
        '_method' : 'DELETE'
    },
    success: function() {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try defining your route that way

```
Route::delete('translation/{id}',array('uses' => 'TranslationController@destroy'));
```

In this case your AJAX won't change. But if you want keep this Route

```
Route::controller('translation', 'TranslationController');
```

You must change your Ajax request to:

```
/* Delete given translation */
var url = "translation/destroy"; // You must specify the action
var id = 1; 

$.ajax({
    method: 'DELETE',
    url: url + '/' + id,
    data: {'_token': token},
    success: function() {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should to send token via header. ( especially in 5.2 version )

```
    $.ajax({
            type: "post", 
            url: "/routeurl",
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token': "{!! csrf_field() !!}" }, 
            success: function(msg){

                 // msg
                     }
            });
```